# handler postDelayed after startActivity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, handler

My DogActivity needs to start a CatActivity. But while CatActivity is running, I need to have some work continue in DogActivity: so that when the user closes CatActivity using `finish()` the result will be ready in DogActivity. But right now if I use a handler, the postDelayed method insists on completing its work before startActivity is called. Does anyone know how I can get startActivity to execute before postDelayed?

Here is my snippet:

```
...
startActivity(intent, 1);
mHandler.postDelayed(doMyWork, 6000);
...
```

Even though `startActivity` comes before `postDelayed`, the postDelayed runnable is always executed first. By the way, the work is to reset a view to a certain value.

Comment: Why don't you move the work from `DogActivity` to a `Service`? Once `DogActivity` resumes you could bind to the service and get the result, if ready; if not the service will notify you when it's ready. To support more this idea, `DogActivity` may be destroyed while `CatActivity` is in the foreground ...

Answer (score 0):

This does not really coincide with how Activities interact with each other. You cannot have the work in ActivityA continue after switching to ActivityB. I would consider looking up IntentService and Service and aid in your solution.